# On clicking on an li a drop-down appears but clicking again on li the drop-down is not closing

Tags: drop-down-menu

I have written HTML for a drop-down menu, but it is not working properly. When I click on ‘Products’ the drop-down menu appears, but when I click again on ‘Products’ the drop down is not closing.

[image]

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-toggle">
  <div class="dropdown-inner" id="dropdown-down"> {% for children in category.children|batch(category.children|length / category.column|round(1, 'ceil')) %}
    <ul class="list-unstyled" id="ul-dropdown">
      {% for child in children %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ child.href }}">{{ child.name }}</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul> 
  {% endfor %}</div>
  {#  <a href="{{ category.href }}" class="see-all">{{ text_all }} {{ category.name }}</a> #} 
</div>
```